# LuaInterface error loading module(Lua for Windows is OK)

Tags: lua, luainterface, loadmodule

While I DoFile:

```
Lua luaVM = new Lua();
luaVM.DoFile("test.lua");
```

This is the error I got.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'LuaInterface.LuaException' occurred in LuaInterface.dll
Additional information: error loading module 'mytestlib' from file '.\mytestlib.dll':
    %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

The dll is I made, It works when I call this lua from LFW(lua for Windows).
Do I need something like a environment variables? (I added the  lua/5.1 folder to EV)

Comment: Hi Peng Zup, have you tried use NLua instead, IIRC the latest version of LuaInterface will not load native .dlls as modules.

Comment: yes, but the lua52.dll in the package seemed not work.

Comment: It looks like you might need to change your project from `Any CPU` to something like `x86` to run as a 32 bit dll (since lua is likely compiled as a 32 bit dll as well).